# How to force change detection on sibling's observable function?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two siblings component. One is a form where you can create a new note. The second one is a UI-container of all notes.
Until now, I had them in one component and when I submitted a new note, the note immediately showed in UI as well.

Now that they are separated, UI can't detect change of a new note. Which is strange because UI component has Observable function which should detect changes right?

I read something about change detection across components but I was unable to get it working.

Both components share the same service for getting and updating notes.

I can get it working if I would setInterval on UI component. But that's is still not instant and definitely a not good practice.

**Form componet**

```
insertLog() {
   this._logsService.insertLog(this.newLog)
    .then((res: any) => {
      if (res.message = 'Log has been succesfully added.') {
        this._notificationService.showNotification('Log has been added!');
        // Force change detection on logs-container component somehow
         // this._logsService.getAllLogs(); <-- this doesn't work

       } 
      }
     });
  }
```

**UI component that should detect changes**

```
getLogs() {
    this.currentShowbtn = 0;
    this._logsService.getAllLogs(this.userIdofCurrent)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.logs = res;
         for (let i = 0; i < this.logs.length; i++) {
          this.logs[i].weekStart = this.getDateOfWeek(this.logs[i].week, 2017);
          this.logs[i].weekEnd = this.getEndingDateOfWeek(this.logs[i].week, 2017);

        }
      });
    }
```

**Common service**

```
 getAllLogs(id) {
    return this._http.post('/api/logs', id)
      .map(result => this.result = result.json().data);
  }
```

Maybe if I could call getLogs from sibling component It would work. But can I? And should I? Isn't there some way how to tell Observable to refresh itself?

Comment: Use a `behaviorSubject` in your service, you can then "push" the data with `next()` into the subject and the `subscribe` will trigger.

Comment: @Fussell Thanks for suggestion, behaviorSubject helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
@Injectable()
export class LogService {

    private logs: BehaviorSubject<any>;

    constructor() {
        this.logs = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    }

    add(log: any) {
        this.logs.next(log);
    }

    getAllLogs(): BehaviorSubject<any> {
        return this.logs;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the `BehaviorSubject` only keeps the last value, there are also other types to subjects if you want all values be triggered to a subscriber, but as you only want a newly inserted value a `BehaviorSubject` should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use output on your form component:

```
@Output() formSave: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
```

In parent template:

```
<your-form-component (formSave)="onFormSaved()"></your-form-component>
```

In parent component:

```
uiData: any;
onFormSaved() {
   uiData = loadNewDataSomehow();
}
```

And in UI component:

```
@Input() data: any;
```

And in parent template:

```
<your-ui-component [data]="uiData"></your-ui-component>
```